# Web assets and SEO - albums on WordPress

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-plus

I'm told that it is considered good SEO practice to have multiple digital properties "around" a website. For example, Youtube, Flikr, Social Media pages etc.

Fine. I have linked my website to my G+ page, for example.

I'm about to upload an album to WordPress. The pictures exist on my G+ album. I was just going to download the pictures from G+ and them re-upload them to my WordPress Gallery.

Is there any SEO value in displaying the album directly from G+, rather than downloading and uploading to WordPress?

This is a specific example, but what about other digital assets like Youtube videos?

What's best practice here? Does this "branch" of SEO, if it exists, have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Does this "branch" of SEO, if it exists, have a name?**

It sound like you're referring to [social media marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media_marketing), which is: "The process of gaining website traffic or attention through social media sites."

> **Is there any SEO value in displaying the album directly from G+, rather than downloading and uploading to WordPress?**

The SEO value from social media marketing is thought of in terms of [social signals](http://moz.com/blog/your-guide-to-social-signals-for-seo). If your images on Google+ aren't linked to or shared from your main website, or even open to the public for search engine indexing (as they often aren't on some social media sites), then there might not be any social signals coming directly from that.

If you upload your images to your WordPress site, and then follow the [image publishing guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en) provided by Google, such as using good `alt` text and descriptive anchor text, then Google might index your images, and you can share and link to them on social media sites to increase the social signals to your site.

There are [image plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/images) for WordPress which may help with this. Also be sure to include the URLs to your images in a sitemap, as covered [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636).

Comment: Dan, thanks for the info I'll do some research on smm and social signals. SOunds interesting

Comment: No problem Doug - always great to have positive feedback on this site. Good luck!